# Обновление страницы клиента со стороны сервера PHP

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Добрый день. Подскажите, как наиболее правильно реализовать обновление информации на странице клиента, если появилась новая информация для отображения? Как пример - чат. Когда пользователь A отправляет сообщение, оно подгружается у пользователя B. На текущий момент реализовал простым setInterval'ом, который просто каждые 5 секунд переподгружает записи из базы, но понимаю, что это очень неправильно.

Comment: Сделайте, что бы оно не подгружало setinterval`ом, а проверяло есть ли новые записи (по количеству, по последней записи и т. д.). А если уже есть новые записи, то оно подгружало уж

Comment: Ну для таких дел обычно используется какой-нибудь WebSocket. Ну либо костыльными `setInterval'ами`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно по таймауту слать ajax запросы на сервер и передавать туда, допустим, lastdate или чего-нибудь и получать только те, которые были позже lastdate. lastdate будет хранится на клиенте и соответственно обновляться, если с сервера пришли последние данные/ Еще можно изпользовать nodejs , socket -ы . Т.е подписать клиента на событие